# Books, videos, and other resources for CEHv7

Tags: certification, professional-education

What are recommenced books, videos and other resources for CEHv7. It seems as though not much is published on the new version of the cert just yet. Currently, I have read All In One CEH by Matt Walker. I plan on taking the test without attending the course as I tend to do better at self study.

Answer (score 2):

Check securitytube.net if you didn't already. It has tons of videos that will help you get a better understanding beyond just CEH.

Answer (score 2):

The content CEHv7 exam is very similar to the CEHv6 one. So if you have any resources for the v6, definitely use it, or get some [CEH related books from Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?field-keywords=ceh). CEH is focused on tools and details, so pay special attention to port numbers, frequently mentioned tools, attack types, ...